# openssl_encrypt creating a different code from an array value that is not decryptable

Tags: php, arrays, encryption

Valuable assistance from members will be greatly appreciated.

I have just begun working on encrypting data stored in MySQL database tables, learning how to encrypt 2-dimensional array values that will be uploaded into tables.

The first problem I am now encountering is that openssl_encrypt is generating different, not decryptable codes compared to when it is generating codes directly from plain text which the latter decrypts without problems.

The second problem is I can’t get the ‘for () {continue} ‘ command to work properly, since I do not want columns or fields [0] and [1] to be encrypted, which is displayed in the this resulting webpage: https://secur-a-doc.com/php-sprdsht-sample6.0

The PHP code I’m using to test is as follows:

```php
<?php
    header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );

    echo "Below is a 3-row, 2-dimensional array displaying sections, fields and values";
    $bgyaa = array (
    '[0]' => array ( 
        '[0]' => '2',
        '[1]' => 'bgyaa.ZBRDE5aTZsUGZmWQ',
        '[2]' => '12346',
        '[3]' => 'John Citizen',
        '[4]' => 'noy-pic-1.jpg',
        '[5]' => 'noy-pic-2.jpg',
        '[6]' => 'RESIDENT',
        '[7]' => '777 Sarangani Street',
        '[8]' => '03/27/84',
        '[9]' => 'B',
        '[10]' => '287-865-194',
        '[11]' =>' '),
    '[1]' => array ( 
        '[0]' => '3',
        '[1]' => 'bgyaa.ZMTEtpTC5qVGNTUQ',
        '[2]' => '12347',
        '[3]' => 'Dominador Pridas',
        '[4]' => 'domeng-pic-1.jpg',
        '[5]' => 'domeng-pic-2.jpg',
        '[6]' => 'TENANT',
        '[7]' => '321 Mango Drive',
        '[8]' => '03/27/84',
        '[9]' => 'B',
        '[10]' => '287-865-194',
        '[11]' =>' ' ),
    '[2]' => array ( 
        '[0]' => '4',
        '[1]' => 'bgyaa.ZpcEpteDJOZlBVQQ',
        '[2]' => '12348',
        '[3]' => 'Taylor Swift',
        '[4]' => 'taylorswift-pic-1.jpg',
        '[5]' => 'taylorswift-pic-2.jpg',
        '[6]' => 'TENANT',
        '[7]' => '826 Anonas Street',
        '[8]' => '03/27/84',
        '[9]' => 'B',
        '[10]' => '287-865-194',
        '[11]' =>' ' ), 
        );


    echo "<pre>";
    foreach ($bgyaa as $section => $items)
        {
            foreach ($items as $key => $value)
            {
                echo "$section:\t$key:\t$value<br/>";
            }
        }                       

    $key="c871754451c2b89d4cdb1b14705be457b7fabe967af6a559f3d20c79ded5b5ff18675e56fa77d75fdcd47c34271bb74e372d6d04652f7aa6f529a838ca4aa6bd";
    $iv= "f1e64276d153ad8a"; // this iv value is 16 bytes of hex characters
    $cipher = "aes-256-cbc-hmac-sha256";

    if (in_array($cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods()))
    {
            $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
        $plain_text = 'John Citizen';
        $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($plain_text, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv);
        echo "<br/><br/><br/>Bellw are from direct encrytion of the plain text name<br/>";
        echo "plain text is John Citizen " . "<br/>";
        echo "encrypted text is " . $encrypted . "<br/><br/><br/>";
    }

        echo "And then below are openssl_encrypt (cipher aes-256-cbc) encrypted array codes beside their plain text original values<br/>";
        echo "NOTE that the encrypted code q+vG/KXTZsYExxV5yX7DFw== for the name John Citizen is different to the above, and not decryptable<br/><br/>";
        foreach ($bgyaa as $section => $items)     // section is the sub array (starts from 0)
            // items are rows
        {
            foreach ($items as $key => $value) 
            //key represents field or column
            //value represents the values of row
            {
            if ($items < 2) 
                {
                    continue; //begin from key or field 4
                    }
                if (in_array($cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods()))
                    {
                        $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);             
                        $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($value, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv);
                    }                   
                    echo $key . " : " . $encrypted . "  :  " . $value . "<br/>";                            
            }
    }
     
    echo "</pre>";   

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the encryption `$key` in your `for` loop.

See:

```php
$key="c871754451c2b89d4cdb1b14705be457b7fabe967af6a559f3d20c79ded5b5ff18675e56fa77d75fdcd47c34271bb74e372d6d04652f7aa6f529a838ca4aa6bd";

...

foreach ($bgyaa as $section => $items) // section is the sub array (starts from 0)
    // items are rows
    {
        foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
            // Now the encryption $key has been overwritten with the index. 
            // In your example, to decrypt 'John Citizen', 
            // You would need to decrypt using '[3]' as the encryption key. 
        }
    }
}
```

Just change the bottom for loop to use a different value for the index variable, like this:

```php
foreach ($items as $index => $value) // changed $key to $index
{
    //key represents field or column
    //value represents the values of row
    if ($items < 2) 
    {
        continue; //begin from key or field 4
    }
    if (in_array($cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods()))
    {
        $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);             
        $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($value, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv);
    }    
    // Changed to also use $index instead of $key.   
    echo $index . " : " . $encrypted . "  :  " . $value . "<br/>";                            
}
```

As for your `continue` problem, do you actually want your indexes to be formatted as strings like `[0]` and `[1]` and not just numbers? If you want numerical indexes, you should just format the arrays like this:

```php
0 => array ( 
    0 => '2',
    1 => 'bgyaa.ZBRDE5aTZsUGZmWQ',
    2' => '12346',
    3 => 'John Citizen'
)
```

Then you can change the `continue` condition to be :

```php
if ($index < 2) 
{
    continue; //begin from key or field 4
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to keep the formatting as literal strings like `"[2]"`, then you'd need to remove the brackets before doing the comparison.

```php
if (str_replace(['[',']'], '', $index) < 2) 
{
    continue; //begin from key or field 4
}
```

To summarize, this is what I'd recommend for the final change with everything applied:

```php
foreach ($items as $index => $value) // changed $key to $index
{
    //key represents field or column
    //value represents the values of row
    //if ($index < 2)  // UNCOMMENT IF YOU USE NUMERICAL INDEXES
    if (str_replace(['[',']'], '', $index) < 2) // KEEP IF YOU USE STRING INDEXES WITH BRACKETS
    {
        continue; //begin from key or field 4
    }
    if (in_array($cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods()))
    {
        $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);             
        $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($value, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv);
    }    
    // Changed to also use $index instead of $key.   
    echo $index . " : " . $encrypted . "  :  " . $value . "<br/>";                            
}
```

Comment: The very first answer to my very first question in this site is simply spot on!  After changing the encryption variable key's name  (which I was overwriting with the parsed field's variable name in the foreach loop), all the encrypted codes came out right and decryptable.  The answer to my second question was also correct although I needed to change the variable that was being tested from $items to $key.  Thank you very much "404 Not Found"!!